# How Can I Use Ubuntu As Firewall Server

Tags: server, firewall

Can **Ubuntu** be configured as a firewall server , if **yes** how ? , if **no** why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in Ubuntu Firewall called `Iptable`.  By default `iptable` allows all traffic. So, you need to configure based on your needs :)

**Here Is Basic Commands on `Iptable`**

Typing

```
sudo iptables -L
```

lists your current rules in iptables. If you have just set up your server, you will have no rules, and you should see

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Please see the whole how to on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

**A simple iptables script**

```
#!/bin/bash
# flush all chains
iptables -F
# set the default policy for each of the pre-defined chains
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
# allow establishment of connections initialised by my outgoing packets
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# drop everything else
iptables -A INPUT -i eth+ -p udp -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth+ -p tcp -m tcp --syn -j DROP
# accept anything on localhost
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

I have network interfaces on eth0 and eth1, so this script has rules which cover both; if your interfaces have different names, you will need to edit the rules to cover that. This drops everything incoming, except for connections which were initially established by my outgoing packets (thanks Luke! - see comments); which means it's no good for servers.

I put this script in /opt/scripts/iptables.script and made it executable. Once you run it, you can find out whether it has worked by displaying your current iptables rules with:

```
sudo iptables -L -v
```

I then created a simple init script to start/stop the firewall in `/etc/init.d/firewall`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == start ]] ; then
  sudo /opt/scripts/iptables.script
else
  sudo iptables -F
fi
```

Then I symlinked this into my `/etc/rc.*` directories using the update-rc.d tool, so the firewall starts before the network comes up:

```
update-rc.d firewall start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 99 0 1 6 .
```

[Source](http://townx.org/simple_firewall_for_ubuntu_using_iptables)

Hope this help :)

Comment: wow .. i was not expecting that much configuration so quick, ,thanksss a lot , +1 , 1st i will try it on virtual machine and let u know ... i m impressed ...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **ufw** [HELP](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/firewall.html) it is a wrapper around iptables, and more easy to configure.